# iMessage stickers too small when put on text message bubble

Tags: ios, imessage

I'm having a weird problem. My stickers are too small when I put them on a text bubble.
All images are 618x618. Sticker Size is set to 4 or 3 column in Xcode.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HQlU.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?